# Windows Authentication in .NET application on domain

Tags: c#, windows, ldap, windows-authentication

I'm looking to create a fairly straight forward application that runs on every machine in a domain, when the user logs into the machine with their user/password it automatically logs them in over client/server and authenticates them with this server.

So really my question is what's the approach (is there a name for this specifically?) to doing this? I'm not exactly sure how Windows Authentication works in this instance, but I can imagine it sending a user and password hash to my little server and verifying it there.

Googling around I can mostly seem to only find doing it with ASP.NET applications and user authentication, but I'm looking to do this with an actual program running within Windows.

I haven't started on the application yet, and just want to make sure everything is covered as much as possible before development starts. Essentially it's an instant messaging application that authenticates automatically when you login to the machine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials.aspx

When you pass the credentials to this "server" you can use these.  Of course you realize you have left this very open ended.  You didnt tell us anything about this client/server application and what it uses to authenticate now.

UPDATE:
Some code that will get the current user info.

```
    WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    textBox1.Text = identity.Name;
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I haven't actually started working on it yet. It will be written in C#. I was sort of just planning it, and wanted to know more about how this sort of authentication works. Essentially it will be a sort of IM system that automatically authenticates when you login to the machine.

Comment: Sounds cool.  There are several ways to skin this cat.  Really its not hard to get the login info for the user.  I would suggest looking for some books or best practices.  I will update my answer with some code that will get you started on the current logged in user.